# Sanitizing XML text in Python (&amp)

Tags: python, html, xml, string, sanitize

I am writing a Python script that imports work items from IBM RTC and exports them to Microsoft ADS. One issue I found is that some strings from RTC xml data are imported with strange text characters such as &amp:

```
9.&amp;#09;Customize the rules for Feature work item
9. Customize the rules for Feature work item

1.&#09;Send out the on-boarding form to Capsule Tech to understand the features/Tools/Customization used by them
1. Send out the on-boarding form to Capsule Tech to understand the features/Tools/Customization used by them

Speed Up RTC-&gt;ADS queries
Speed Up RTC->ADS queries
```

I've tried using the following code to sanitize and normalize the text:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from html import unescape


    soup = BeautifulSoup(unescape(rtc_title), 'lxml')
    ads_title=soup.text
```

But it is replacing the characters with tabs most of the time, which is incorrect:

```
1.\tSend out the on-boarding form to Capsule Tech to understand the features/Tools/Customization used by them
```

is there a better way to parse and normalize these strings taken from IBM RTC xml data?
Thanks

Comment: The replacement of &#09; is correct for an html escape sequence https://mateam.net/html-escape-characters/, question is, how it got there... is simple replacement of these unwanted escape sequences an option? .replace("#09;", "").replace("&amp:", "")....?

Comment: If the escape sequences are in an XML document then you should be reading the document using an XML parser which will interpret them correctly. (But perhaps I'd understand the question better if I knew what RTC and ADS are).